# Socket IO -- socket.emit firing every event twice

Tags: node.js, socket.io

socket.js:

```
var state = {
  io: null
}

exports.init = function(io) {
  state.io = io;
}

exports.get = function() {
  return state.io;
}

exports.emit = function(message, data) {
  console.log("emitting")
  state.io.emit(message, data);
}


exports.onConnection = function(callback) {
  state.io.once('connection', function (socket) {
    callback(socket);
  });
}
```

tags.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var DeviceIdentifier = 'WILL'
    var NDefRecord = 'FROM_WILL'
    req.headers['x-name'] = DeviceIdentifier
    req.headers['x-content'] = NDefRecord

    console.log("tags.js: GET");

    socket.emit("tag:scan", {name: "000000000a0d9439", content: "adsf});


})
```

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var socket = require('./socket');
socket.init(io);

socket.onConnection(function (data) {
  console.log("Got Connection");
  console.log(data);
});
```

No matter how I am doing it, the socket.emit function is called twice and data is getting stored twice as well.

I've tried looking up many examples and the problem still seems like it is persisting

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using tags.js?

Comment: Different issue, but your use of `.once()` is likely flawed.  You have no way of knowing the timing of when a connection event is going to arrive.

Comment: @jens Added tags.js

Comment: Does `tags.js: GET` console log more than once?

Comment: @jens No, it fires once

Answer (score 0):

just add res.send . you are not sending any response to the browser so he try to refresh after x seconds

```js
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var DeviceIdentifier = 'WILL'
    var NDefRecord = 'FROM_WILL'
    req.headers['x-name'] = DeviceIdentifier
    req.headers['x-content'] = NDefRecord

    console.log("tags.js: GET");

    socket.emit("tag:scan", {name: "000000000a0d9439", content: "adsf});
    res.send('ok');

})
```

Comment: Thanks. Though this doesn't solve the original issue, it's still something that I should look into

Comment: you are also missing a " in the end of the object {name: "000000000a0d9439", content: "adsf"} and it was {name: "000000000a0d9439", content: "adsf}